# Django retrieve data from html form

Tags: python, django

this is my form in html

```
<form action="#about" method="POST">
 {%csrf_token%}
<h2>Signup today</h2>
<input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" required="">

<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" required="">

<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your password" required="">

<button class="submit-btn form-control" id="form-submit">Get started</button>
</form>
```

and this is views.py

```
def Student(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print('this post')
        name =request.POST['name']
        email =request.POST['email']
        print(name, email)  
    return render(request,'#about')
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
      path('',views.index, name='index.html'),  
      path('',views.Student, name="#about"),  
]
```

I'm new to Django and I spent the last 24h trying to get this right, it doesn't show any error but it doesn't print any of what there is in views.py and it doesn't retrieve form data as well, could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to properly retrieve html data form to django? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `path('',views.index, name='index.html'),  
path('',views.Student, name="#about"),`

why both paths are `''`

set one of them to `'/'` and the other to` '/students'`

Comment: I just tried it , and also added the type="submit "and it still doesn't print out or get any data

Comment: are you sending post  request?

Comment: yes, also I guess I didn't know how to specify the path to 'Student.view' because I just copied what's written in STUDENT.VIEW in the index.view which is this (def index(request): return render(request,"index.html") ), and it worked, i still don't know what's wrong but you made it clear that's with the path, if you explain how it does really work, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your button need `type="submit"`
like this:

```
<button class="submit-btn form-control" id="form-submit" type="submit">Get started</button>
```

Comment: thank you for the note it brings me close to what I want , but it still doesn't print out or get any data :c

Comment: how about try this: action="{% url 'APP_NAME:Student' %}"